# On Device: Can't find keyplane that supports type 11 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitTruffle-NumberPad;

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm working on a react native app where we have a checkout page. For whatever reason on the device, when I go to enter my card information the application freezes and crashes. In Xcode's log, I get this error:

**Can't find keyplane that supports type 11 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitTruffle-NumberPad; using 25764_PortraitTruffle_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default**

The funny thing is when I run the app on the simulator **react-native run-ios** the app works perfectly, the keyboard loads, and I am able to check out my items.

I also tried iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard and no luck there.

I have been troubleshooting all day and I am not sure what the issue could be. I tried to reinstall **pod install** and **npm install**. For every other page in the app the keyboard loads with no issue. It's just this page where the app crashes when the keyboard is supposed to load.

````
import {
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,  View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text, Image, 
  Dimensions, FlatList, KeyboardAvoidingView, ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';
import Tabs from '../../components/consumer/tab/Tabs';
import { Divider } from 'react-native-elements';
import Textarea from 'react-native-textarea';
import  stripe, { PaymentCardTextField } from 'tipsi-stripe';
import cartService from '../../services/cartService';
import GetLocation from 'react-native-get-location';
import axios from 'axios';
stripe.setOptions({
  publishableKey: ''
  })

export default class CheckoutPage extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectTab: 'none',
      valid: false,
      token : '',
      loading : false,
      params: {
        number: '',
        expMonth: 0,
        expYear: 0,
        cvc: '',
      },
    }
  } 
  UNSAFE_componentWillMount(){

    GetLocation.getCurrentPosition({
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 15000,
    })
    .then(location => {
      this.setState({currentLat : location.latitude});
      this.setState({currentLng : location.longitude});

      var productlist = this.props.navigation.state.params.navParam.productlist;
      var cartId = this.props.navigation.state.params.navParam.cartId;
      var cartlist = this.props.navigation.state.params.navParam.cartlist;

      var product_fee = 0;
      var productPrice = 0;
      var totalProductPrice = 0;
      for( var i=0; i<productlist.length; i++){
        product_fee =  5;
        productPrice =  productlist[i].productPrice * productlist[i].buyQuantity;
        totalProductPrice =  totalProductPrice + productlist[i].productPrice * productlist[i].buyQuantity;
      }
      this.setState({product_fee : (product_fee)});
      this.setState({productPrice : (productPrice)});
      this.setState({totalProductPrice : (totalProductPrice)});
      this.setState({productlist : productlist});
      this.setState({cartId : cartId});
      this.setState({cartlist : cartlist});      

    })
    .catch(error => {
        const { code, message } = error;
        console.log('error');
        console.warn(code, message);
    })  
  }

  handleFieldParamsChange = ( valid, params) => {
    this.setState({
      valid,
      params,
    });
  }

  checkOut = async () => {

    console.log("valide", this.state.valid);
    this.setState({ loading: true, token: null });
    var number = this.state.params.number;
    var expMonth = this.state.params.expMonth;
    var expYear = this.state.params.expYear;
    var cvc = this.state.params.cvc;
    const tokenObject = await stripe.createTokenWithCard({
      number, expYear, expMonth, cvc
    });
    this.setState({ token: tokenObject.tokenId });
    var totalPrice = Math.round((this.state.totalProductPrice + this.state.product_fee + this.state.totalProductPrice * 0.089) * 100);
    axios({
      method : 'POST',
      url : '',
      data : {
        amount: (totalPrice),
        currency : 'usd',
        token : this.state.token,
        cartId : this.state.cartId,
        lat : this.state.currentLat,
        lng : this.state.currentLng
      },
    }).then(response =>{      

      this.state.cartlist[0].amount = (totalPrice * 100);
      this.state.cartlist[0].currency = 'usd';
      this.state.cartlist[0].status = "paid";
      this.setState({loading: false});


      cartService.updateCheckOutStatus(this.state.cartlist[0], this.state.currentLat, this.state.currentLng).then(result=>{

         this.props.navigation.navigate('TrackingPage');
       });

      var first_name;
      var last_name;
      var address;
      var phonenumber;

      cartService.getDeliveryInfo(this.state.cartId).then(result =>{
        result.forEach(function(consumerInfo){
        console.log('consumerInfo', consumerInfo);
        first_name = consumerInfo.val().first_name;
        last_name = consumerInfo.val().last_name;
        address = consumerInfo.val().address;
        phonenumber = consumerInfo.val().phonenumber;   

      });

      this.setState({first_name : first_name});
      this.setState({last_name : last_name});
      this.setState({address : address});
      this.setState({phonenumber : phonenumber});
    });

      axios({
        method : 'POST',
        url : '',
        data : {
        "cartId" : this.state.cartId,
        "first_name" : this.state.first_name,
        "last_name" : this.state.last_name,
        "phonenumber" : this.state.phonenumber,
        "totalProductPrice" : (totalPrice/100),
        "address" : this.state.address
      }
      });
    });
};

  render(){
    const { valid, params } = this.state
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
        <View style={{ marginLeft : '10%', height : 50, justifyContent : 'flex-end'}}> 
          <Text style={{fontSize:20, fontWeight : '400'}}>Order Summary</Text>
        </View>
        <Divider style={{ marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: '#a0a3a0' }} />

        <FlatList
            data={this.state.productlist}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={{width : '100%'}}>
              <View style={styles.textview}> 
                <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}>{item.product_name} x {item.buyQuantity}</Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}>$ {item.productPrice * item.buyQuantity}</Text>
              </View>   
              {/*<View style={styles.textview}> 
                <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}>Delivery Fee</Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}>$ {this.state.product_fee}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.textview}> 
                <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}> Sales Tax</Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}>$ {(this.state.productPrice * 0.04)}</Text>
            </View>*/}
              <Divider style={{ margin: 20, backgroundColor: '#a0a3a0' }} />
            </View>            
            )}
          //Setting the number of column
          numColumns={1}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          />

         <View style={styles.totaltextview}>
         <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}>Subtotal</Text>
         <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}>$ {this.state.totalProductPrice}</Text>
         </View>

         <View style={styles.totaltextview}>
         <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}>Sales Tax (8.9%)</Text>
         <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}>$ {Math.round((this.state.totalProductPrice * 0.089 + Number.EPSILON) * 100)/100}</Text>
         </View>

         <View style={styles.totaltextview}>
         <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}>Delivery Fee</Text>
         <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}>$ {this.state.product_fee}</Text>
         </View>

          <View style={styles.totaltextview}> 
            <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}>Total Amount</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400', color : '#cf4a08'}}>$ { Math.round((this.state.totalProductPrice + this.state.product_fee + (this.state.totalProductPrice * 0.089) + Number.EPSILON) * 100) /100 }</Text>
          </View>            
          {/*<View style={{flexDirection : 'row', justifyContent : 'center', marginTop : 20}}>
            <View style={styles.paymentmethodview}>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/imgs/visa.png')} ></Image>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.paymentmethodview}>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/imgs/mastercard.png')} ></Image>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.paymentmethodview}>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/imgs/express.png')} ></Image>
            </View>
            {/* <View style={styles.paymentmethodview}>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/imgs/paypal.png')} ></Image>
            </View>                                    
          </View>*/} 

          <View style={{marginLeft : '10%', marginTop : 20}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400', marginBottom : 10}}>Card Number</Text>


// Issue lays here
            <PaymentCardTextField
              // ref={ (ref) => {
              //     this.paymentCardInput = ref;
              // }}
              style={styles.field}

              onParamsChange={this.handleFieldParamsChange}
              numberPlaceholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX"
              expirationPlaceholder="MM/YY"
              cvcPlaceholder="CVC"

              disabled={false}
          />          
          </View>
          <View style={{marginLeft : '10%', marginTop : 20}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight : '400'}}> Enter Delivery Information</Text>

// Issue lays here
            <Textarea
                  containerStyle={styles.textareaContainer}
                // style={styles.textarea}
                // onChangeText={this.onChange}
                // defaultValue={this.state.text}
                maxLength={500}
                placeholder={'Address, Phone # and Full Name'}
                placeholderTextColor={'#949597'}
                underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
            />  
          </View>   
          {this.state.loading &&
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E"/>
          }
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.checkOut()}>
            <View style={styles.addcart}>
              <Text style={styles.addcarttext}>Check Out</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>  

        </ScrollView>

        <Tabs 
          gotoAddNewCartPage={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AddNewCartPage')}
          gotoProductCategoryPage={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductCategoryPage')}
          gotoProfilePage={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfilePage')}
          gotoSearchStorePage={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SearchStorePage')}
          selectTab={this.state.selectTab}
          />           
      </SafeAreaView>

    );
  }
}
const screenWidth = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    flex : 1, 
    justifyContent : 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF'
  },
  textview : {
    marginLeft : '10%', 
    marginRight : '10%', 
    marginTop: 20, 
    flexDirection : 'row', 
    justifyContent : 'space-between'
  },
  applyview : {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems : 'center',
      width : '90%',
      height: 50,
      borderRadius : 15,
      borderColor : '#b3b0ad',
      borderWidth : 1 ,
      marginTop : 10,
      marginRight : '10%'   
  },
  buttonview : {
    backgroundColor : '#23b825',
    width : '40%',
    height : 50,
    alignItems : 'center',
    justifyContent : 'center',
    borderBottomRightRadius : 15,
    borderTopRightRadius : 15
  },
  inputtext : {
      marginLeft : 10,
      width : '60%',
      height: 50,
  },

  totaltextview : {
      marginLeft : '10%', 
      marginRight : '10%', 
      marginBottom : 40,
      flexDirection : 'row', 
      justifyContent : 'space-between'
  },
  paymentmethodview : {
      width : screenWidth/4,
      height : 100,
      borderWidth  : 1,
      borderColor : '#b3b3b3',
      alignItems : 'center',
      justifyContent : 'center',
      borderRadius : 10,
      marginRight : 10
  },
  cardnumber : {
      borderWidth : 1,
      width : '90%',
      height : 50,
      borderRadius : 10,
      borderColor : '#b3b3b3',
      padding : 10,
      marginTop : 10
  },
  textareaContainer : {
      borderWidth : 1,
      borderColor : '#b3b3b3',
      width : '90%',
      height : 100,
      marginTop : 10
  },
  addcarttext : {
      color : 'white',
      fontSize : 22,
      fontWeight : '400'
  },
  addcart: {
      backgroundColor:'#61d273',
      width : '80%',
      height: 50,
      borderRadius:20,
      justifyContent : 'center',
      alignItems : 'center',
      shadowColor: '#919090',
      shadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.9,
      elevation: 10, 
      marginLeft : '10%',
      marginBottom : 20 ,
      marginTop : 20 
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instruction: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  token: {
    height: 20,
  },
  spoiler: {
    width: 300,
  },
  params: {
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
    margin: 5,
  },
  field: {
    width: '90%',
    color: '#449aeb',
    borderColor: '#b3b3b3',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },  
});```
````